# How to find all processes using a device

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

I have a very major issue with determining whether I can find which processes are using a device.
What I'm currently doing is using the SysInternals [handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) program to find all the open 'handles'.

However, since the program is licensed and I want to learn to do it myself in C# I was wondering whether it were possible using the Win32 API alone.

All documentation links are welcome.

**EDIT:**
Looking to be able to search for something like

```
\Device\00000034
```

Comment: `handle.exe` is written using the Win32 API so yes, it's possible.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - I may be wrong, but I think handle loads an embedded kernel driver to do its magic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fuser SourceForge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuserforwin32/?source=directory)

I wrote this utility in "C" that tries to mimic what Systinternal's utility "handle.exe" does, and made it a SourceForge project.  You might have to modify the source code to make it do what you need it to do.

The code is very ugly, in that there are a number of "undocumented" (not necessarily unsupported) things being done.

I hope this helps (and I think it might)...

I realize it is written in "C", but hopefully you can "translate" the functionality to C#.

Comment: Interesting project. Just as a data point, I once inquired about licencing handle.exe from SysInternals (long before Microsoft bought them), and was quoted a price of $50,000. Nice of you to give this away for free :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be delighted to inspect your code.

Comment: Thanks.  That's very interesting.  I just know that the developers at Microsoft had to have been using the sysinternal utilities for kernel development way back when.  I cobbled this together from knowledge all over the web.  There was a lot of time spent banging my head against my desk trying to figure this out, also trying to support multiple Windows operating systems.  It is nowhere near the quality of the sysinternals utility, but it generally works.  I hope - I haven't tested it in a few years.

Comment: Well crap, I just found out it doesn't work under Windows 10.

Comment: By the way, do you know if it's possible to search for a device directly with your awesome tool? It works fine for files, but for example if I need to find \Device\00000034

Comment: There...I just modified the fuser project in sourceforge.  It didn't quite work on newer operating systems.  Now it seems to.  Yes, just run this: fuser \Device\00000034     It will show all processes that have an open handle to it.  Warning: this thing runs fairly slowly.  In my tests, it took 21 seconds to run, which is muuuuuuch slower than what it used to be.

Comment: I just realized your solution works perfectly fine on Windows 8.1, But anyways ENJOY YOUR BOUNTY :D

Comment: The [Restart Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc948910.aspx) can be used to [find out which process has a file open](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx). I don't know, if this applies to devices as well, and haven't had the time to check this myself. Maybe this is something you can try to implement in your tool, to have a robust solution for Windows Vista and above.

Comment: @IInspectable very interesting, if the code is available I'll give it a peek ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I found a C#-Only Solution!**

It takes about 4-5 seconds to process results and I've only tested it on Windows 8.1, but it definitely works pretty well and you don't need any device drivers or other extra components (like C).

Here is a bit of code which will print all the processes accessing `\\Device\0000003a`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HandleUtil
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Process> procs = Win32Processes.GetProcessesLockingFile("\\Device\\0000003a");
            foreach(var proc in procs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        internal class Win32API
        {
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int
                ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
                ref int returnLength);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int
                SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength,
                ref int returnLength);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
               ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
               uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

            public enum ObjectInformationClass : int
            {
                ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
                ObjectNameInformation = 1,
                ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
                ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
                ObjectHandleInformation = 4
            }

            [Flags]
            public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
            {
                All = 0x001F0FFF,
                Terminate = 0x00000001,
                CreateThread = 0x00000002,
                VMOperation = 0x00000008,
                VMRead = 0x00000010,
                VMWrite = 0x00000020,
                DupHandle = 0x00000040,
                SetInformation = 0x00000200,
                QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
                Synchronize = 0x00100000
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 0
                public int Attributes;
                public int GrantedAccess;
                public int HandleCount;
                public int PointerCount;
                public int PagedPoolUsage;
                public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
                public int Reserved1;
                public int Reserved2;
                public int Reserved3;
                public int NameInformationLength;
                public int TypeInformationLength;
                public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
                public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 2
                public UNICODE_STRING Name;
                public int ObjectCount;
                public int HandleCount;
                public int Reserved1;
                public int Reserved2;
                public int Reserved3;
                public int Reserved4;
                public int PeakObjectCount;
                public int PeakHandleCount;
                public int Reserved5;
                public int Reserved6;
                public int Reserved7;
                public int Reserved8;
                public int InvalidAttributes;
                public GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
                public int ValidAccess;
                public byte Unknown;
                public byte MaintainHandleDatabase;
                public int PoolType;
                public int PagedPoolUsage;
                public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 1
                public UNICODE_STRING Name;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            public struct UNICODE_STRING
            {
                public ushort Length;
                public ushort MaximumLength;
                public IntPtr Buffer;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct GENERIC_MAPPING
            {
                public int GenericRead;
                public int GenericWrite;
                public int GenericExecute;
                public int GenericAll;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 16
                public int ProcessID;
                public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
                public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
                public ushort Handle;
                public int Object_Pointer;
                public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
            }

            public const int MAX_PATH = 260;
            public const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
            public const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
        }
        public class Win32Processes
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Return a list of processes that hold on the given file.
            /// </summary>
            public static List<Process> GetProcessesLockingFile(string filePath)
            {
                var procs = new List<Process>();

                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    var files = GetFilesLockedBy(process);
                    if (files.Contains(filePath)) procs.Add(process);
                }
                return procs;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Return a list of file locks held by the process.
            /// </summary>
            public static List<string> GetFilesLockedBy(Process process)
            {
                var outp = new List<string>();

                ThreadStart ts = delegate {
                    /*try
                    {
                        outp = UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(process);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }*/
                    outp = UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(process);
                };


                try
                {
                    var t = new Thread(ts);
                    t.Start();
                    if (!t.Join(250))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            t.Abort();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                return outp;
            }

            private static List<string> UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(Process process)
            {
                var handles = GetHandles(process);
                var files = new List<string>();

                for(int i = 0; i < handles.Count; i++)
                {
                    var handle = handles[i];
                    var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                    //Console.WriteLine(file);
                    if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                }

                //foreach (var handle in handles)
                //{
                //    var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                //    Console.WriteLine(file);
                //    if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                //}

                return files;
                /*try
                {
                    var handles = GetHandles(process);
                    var files = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var handle in handles)
                    {
                        var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                        if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                    }

                    return files;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new List<string>();
                }*/
            }

            const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 16;
            const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xc0000004;
            private static string GetFilePath(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION sYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, Process process)
            {
                IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objObjectType = new Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objObjectName = new Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
                string strObjectTypeName = "";
                string strObjectName = "";
                int nLength = 0;
                int nReturn = 0;
                IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

                if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, sYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                    return null;

                ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
                Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation, ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
                objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);


                ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objBasic.TypeInformationLength);
                nLength = objBasic.TypeInformationLength;
                while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectTypeInformation, ipObjectType, nLength, ref nLength)) == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                    ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }

                objObjectType = (Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectType, objObjectType.GetType());
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectType.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipTemp = objObjectType.Name.Buffer;
                }

                strObjectTypeName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipTemp, objObjectType.Name.Length >> 1);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                if (strObjectTypeName != "File")
                    return null;

                nLength = objBasic.NameInformationLength;

                ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectNameInformation, ipObjectName, nLength, ref nLength)) == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                    ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }
                objObjectName = (Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectName, objObjectName.GetType());
                //
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectName.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipTemp = objObjectName.Name.Buffer;
                }

                if (ipTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if(nLength < 0)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
                    try
                    {
                        Marshal.Copy(ipTemp, baTemp, 0, nLength);

                        strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Is64Bits() ? new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt64()) : new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt32()));
                    }
                    catch (Exception)    //AccessViolationException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                        Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                    }
                }

                string path = GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(strObjectName);
                try
                {
                    return path;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private static string GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(string strRawName)
            {
                string strFileName = strRawName;
                foreach (string strDrivePath in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
                {
                    StringBuilder sbTargetPath = new StringBuilder(Win32API.MAX_PATH);
                    if (Win32API.QueryDosDevice(strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2), sbTargetPath, Win32API.MAX_PATH) == 0)
                    {
                        return strRawName;
                    }
                    string strTargetPath = sbTargetPath.ToString();
                    if (strFileName.StartsWith(strTargetPath))
                    {
                        strFileName = strFileName.Replace(strTargetPath, strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return strFileName;
            }

            private static List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> GetHandles(Process process)
            {
                uint nStatus;
                int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
                IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
                int nLength = 0;
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer, nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }

                byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
                Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

                long lHandleCount = 0;
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
                }

                Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
                List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

                for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
                {
                    shHandle = new Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
                    if (Is64Bits())
                    {
                        shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                        ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                        shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                    }
                    if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
                    lstHandles.Add(shHandle);
                }
                return lstHandles;

            }

            private static bool Is64Bits()
            {
                return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in user3788486's answer works but is missing a `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);` at the end of line ~430 leading to memory leakage.

The code would look like this after this change:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HandleUtil
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Process> procs = Win32Processes.GetProcessesLockingFile("\\Device\\0000003a");
            foreach(var proc in procs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        internal class Win32API
        {
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int
                ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
                ref int returnLength);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int
                SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength,
                ref int returnLength);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
               ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
               uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

            public enum ObjectInformationClass : int
            {
                ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
                ObjectNameInformation = 1,
                ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
                ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
                ObjectHandleInformation = 4
            }

            [Flags]
            public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
            {
                All = 0x001F0FFF,
                Terminate = 0x00000001,
                CreateThread = 0x00000002,
                VMOperation = 0x00000008,
                VMRead = 0x00000010,
                VMWrite = 0x00000020,
                DupHandle = 0x00000040,
                SetInformation = 0x00000200,
                QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
                Synchronize = 0x00100000
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 0
                public int Attributes;
                public int GrantedAccess;
                public int HandleCount;
                public int PointerCount;
                public int PagedPoolUsage;
                public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
                public int Reserved1;
                public int Reserved2;
                public int Reserved3;
                public int NameInformationLength;
                public int TypeInformationLength;
                public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
                public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 2
                public UNICODE_STRING Name;
                public int ObjectCount;
                public int HandleCount;
                public int Reserved1;
                public int Reserved2;
                public int Reserved3;
                public int Reserved4;
                public int PeakObjectCount;
                public int PeakHandleCount;
                public int Reserved5;
                public int Reserved6;
                public int Reserved7;
                public int Reserved8;
                public int InvalidAttributes;
                public GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
                public int ValidAccess;
                public byte Unknown;
                public byte MaintainHandleDatabase;
                public int PoolType;
                public int PagedPoolUsage;
                public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 1
                public UNICODE_STRING Name;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            public struct UNICODE_STRING
            {
                public ushort Length;
                public ushort MaximumLength;
                public IntPtr Buffer;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct GENERIC_MAPPING
            {
                public int GenericRead;
                public int GenericWrite;
                public int GenericExecute;
                public int GenericAll;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
            { // Information Class 16
                public int ProcessID;
                public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
                public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
                public ushort Handle;
                public int Object_Pointer;
                public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
            }

            public const int MAX_PATH = 260;
            public const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
            public const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
        }
        public class Win32Processes
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Return a list of processes that hold on the given file.
            /// </summary>
            public static List<Process> GetProcessesLockingFile(string filePath)
            {
                var procs = new List<Process>();

                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    var files = GetFilesLockedBy(process);
                    if (files.Contains(filePath)) procs.Add(process);
                }
                return procs;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Return a list of file locks held by the process.
            /// </summary>
            public static List<string> GetFilesLockedBy(Process process)
            {
                var outp = new List<string>();

                ThreadStart ts = delegate {
                    /*try
                    {
                        outp = UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(process);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }*/
                    outp = UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(process);
                };


                try
                {
                    var t = new Thread(ts);
                    t.Start();
                    if (!t.Join(250))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            t.Abort();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                return outp;
            }
            
            private static List<string> UnsafeGetFilesLockedBy(Process process)
            {
                var handles = GetHandles(process);
                var files = new List<string>();

                for(int i = 0; i < handles.Count; i++)
                {
                    var handle = handles[i];
                    var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                    //Console.WriteLine(file);
                    if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                }

                //foreach (var handle in handles)
                //{
                //    var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                //    Console.WriteLine(file);
                //    if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                //}

                return files;
                /*try
                {
                    var handles = GetHandles(process);
                    var files = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var handle in handles)
                    {
                        var file = GetFilePath(handle, process);
                        if (file != null) files.Add(file);
                    }

                    return files;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new List<string>();
                }*/
            }

            const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 16;
            const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xc0000004;
            private static string GetFilePath(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION sYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, Process process)
            {
                IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objObjectType = new Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
                var objObjectName = new Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
                string strObjectTypeName = "";
                string strObjectName = "";
                int nLength = 0;
                int nReturn = 0;
                IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

                if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, sYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                    return null;

                ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
                Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation, ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
                objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);


                ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objBasic.TypeInformationLength);
                nLength = objBasic.TypeInformationLength;
                while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectTypeInformation, ipObjectType, nLength, ref nLength)) == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                    ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }

                objObjectType = (Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectType, objObjectType.GetType());
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectType.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipTemp = objObjectType.Name.Buffer;
                }

                strObjectTypeName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipTemp, objObjectType.Name.Length >> 1);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                if (strObjectTypeName != "File")
                    return null;

                nLength = objBasic.NameInformationLength;

                ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectNameInformation, ipObjectName, nLength, ref nLength)) == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                    ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }
                objObjectName = (Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectName, objObjectName.GetType());
                //
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectName.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipTemp = objObjectName.Name.Buffer;
                }

                if (ipTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if(nLength < 0)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
                    try
                    {
                        Marshal.Copy(ipTemp, baTemp, 0, nLength);

                        strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Is64Bits() ? new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt64()) : new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt32()));
                    }
                    catch (Exception)    //AccessViolationException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                        Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                    }
                }

                string path = GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(strObjectName);
                try
                {
                    return path;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private static string GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(string strRawName)
            {
                string strFileName = strRawName;
                foreach (string strDrivePath in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
                {
                    StringBuilder sbTargetPath = new StringBuilder(Win32API.MAX_PATH);
                    if (Win32API.QueryDosDevice(strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2), sbTargetPath, Win32API.MAX_PATH) == 0)
                    {
                        return strRawName;
                    }
                    string strTargetPath = sbTargetPath.ToString();
                    if (strFileName.StartsWith(strTargetPath))
                    {
                        strFileName = strFileName.Replace(strTargetPath, strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return strFileName;
            }

            private static List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> GetHandles(Process process)
            {
                uint nStatus;
                int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
                IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
                int nLength = 0;
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer, nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }

                byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
                Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

                long lHandleCount = 0;
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
                }

                Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
                List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

                for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
                {
                    shHandle = new Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
                    if (Is64Bits())
                    {
                        shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                        ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                        shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                    }
                    if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
                    lstHandles.Add(shHandle);
                }

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);

                return lstHandles;

            }

            private static bool Is64Bits()
            {
                return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```