# What does Windows IOCTL code 0x83350048 do?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ioctl, sysinternals

I can find:

```
#define CTL_CODE( DeviceType, Function, Method, Access ) (                 \
    ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method) \
```

in `winioctl.h`. However, I still can't understand this control code. For instance, what is a DeviceType of 0x8335? I just can't find such DeviceType in this header file. Or did I misunderstand this CTL_CODE macro?

This control code is frequently used in [sysinternals handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/handle). It seems to use this control code in DeviceIoControl to query file handle information. I want to integrate this function in my application but I can't figure out how to use this IOCTL. I failed to find helpful information in either Microsoft Learn.

[This super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/1426689/in-the-output-of-sysinternals-handle-exe-what-does-rwd-stand-for) mentioned this code but very shortly and I still don't know how to use it.

So finally what does this code do and how can I use it in my application?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think the `DeviceControl` function would solve it? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to be able to write a meaningful answer.

Comment: I'd guess its an undocumented part of the windows internals which is why you can't find any documentation on it

Comment: That is just one of the IOCTLs used to communicate with the sysinternals driver. The actual value is somewhat arbitrary as long as both sides agree on what it is.

Comment: According to [Defining I/O Control Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/defining-i-o-control-codes): "*[Device Type] Values of 0x8000 and higher can be used by vendors. **Note that the vendor-assigned values set the Common bit**.*" `0x8335` has the `Common` bit set. [Specifying Device Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-device-types) also says: "*If a type of hardware does not match any of the defined types, specify a value of either FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, or **a value within the range of 32768 through 65535**.*"

Comment: As for what it does, it looks like the driver primarily calls `ObQueryNameString` and returns the result to the client.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well I was affected by some other suggestions that you should show your effort to get the answer yourself so that potential answerers will be more interested in your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As for what exactly I'm trying to do: I want to list file handles of any process in my own application. And also, I want to know where does the DeviceType 0x8335 come from, since it's not documented. The handle.exe does not seem to be from any specific vendor.

Comment: The handle.exe is from Microsoft vendor. Does the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580420/how-to-find-all-processes-using-a-device work for you?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT No. They mainly use the NtQueryObject route, which is also the technical route used by Windows Resource Monitor. But NtQueryObject is unreliable, and for some file handles this function never returns. I found that Handle.exe can use the DeviceIoControl route to access handles that cannot be queried with NtQueryObject, so I tried to understand IOCTL usage.